# Ruby - iterate over array of irregularly repeating hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash, iteration

Example input array of hashes ( with some regular and irregular repeating pattern )  :

```
[{ key1 => value1 }, { key2 => value2 }, { key3 => value3 }, 
 { key4 => value4 }, { key3 => value5 }, { key4 => value6 }, 
 { key1 => value7 }, { key2 => value8 }, { key3 => value9 }, 
 { key4 => value10 }, { key3 => value11 }, { key4 =>  value12 }, { key3  => value13 }, { key4 => value14 },
 { key1 => value15 }, { key2 => value16 }, { key3 =>   value17 }, { key4 => value18 } ]
```

Requirement is to convert the above to this :

```
 [ [{ key1 => value1 }, { key2 => value2 },
    { key3key4 => value3value4value5value6 } ]
   [ { key1 => value7 }, { key2 => value8 }, 
     { key3key4 =>       value9value10value11value12value13value14 }]
   [ { key1 => value15 }, { key2 => value16 }, { key3key4 =>   value17value18 }] ]
```

( note, e.g., key3key4 and  value5value6value7value8 etc, are just concatenations of the keys and values )

The input structure could be of any number of repeating hashes with key3 and key4 appearing irregularly, sometimes just two hashes, sometimes 3 etc..

I understand array.each and array.map etc, and I think to achieve the above it may need counters or similar employed, but so far my efforts have quickly ended up in a tangled mess, hence posting here for some advice on how best to tackle this.

Edit: a little more rationale, key3 and key4 ( and their values ) get concatenated as they are the keys where the hashes repeat ( irregularly ) in each loop of the pattern, and there is desire to collapse that down into one key:value pair hash in each ‘repeat’ of the pattern in the output. The values are strings in real problem and it makes sense when they are concatenated

Comment: Could you edit your post and add more rationale. Why did key3 and key4 get concatenated when key1 and key2 did not, for example?

Comment: Thanks, I added some extra text at the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the hashes repeat after all the `key3` and `key4`, then `key1` will always be the first key, so we can use that and the [`slice_before`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_before) method on arrays to split the array into the proper groupings:

```
output = input.slice_before { |hash| hash.has_key?('key1') }
```

If the condition for a grouping isn't as simple as just 'always start with `key1`, you can use [`slice_when`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when) to split a group when 2 adjacent hashes occur where the first contains a concatenate-able key and the second does not:

```
output = input.slice_when do |current_hash, next_hash|
  concatenate_keys.any? { |key| current_hash.has_key?(key) } &&
    concatenate_keys.none? { |key| next_hash.has_key?(key) }
end
```

From there, we just need to go through and collapse all `key3` and `key4` hashes into a single hash, which we can do with [`map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-map), [`select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-select) and [`reject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Array.html#method-i-reject):

```
concatenate_keys = %w[key3 key4]
contains_concatenate_key = -> hash { concatenate_keys.any? { |key| hash.has_key?(key) } }

output = output.map do |grouping|
  concatenatable_hashes = grouping.select &contains_concatenate_key

  grouping.reject(&contains_concatenate_key) + [
    { concatenate_keys.join => concatenatable_hashes.flat_map(&:values).join }
  ]
end

p output
# => [[{"key1"=>"value1"}, {"key2"=>"value2"}, {"key3key4"=>"value3value4value5value6"}],
#     [{"key1"=>"value7"}, {"key2"=>"value8"}, {"key3key4"=>"value9value10value11value12value13value14"}],
#     [{"key1"=>"value15"}, {"key2"=>"value16"}, {"key3key4"=>"value17value18"}]]
```

Comment: Ah slice_when and slice_before, thanks. Yes, the key1 is always at the start of the sequence, followed by key2 and then key3 and key4, where key3 and key4 can repeat any number of times in any single key1 starting sequence.